# Play ogg file using ffplay / ffmpeg on .NET

Tags: vb.net, audio, ffmpeg, x86, ogg

I'm trying to play an Ogg file in VB.NET using `ffplay.exe` but I don't know exactly how.
This is my code:

```
Private Sub ButtonIR_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonIR.Click
    If IsNotNothing(TextBoxSource.text) Then
        TextBoxDETALLES.Clear()
        Try
            Dim CONVERSOR As New Process

            CONVERSOR.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\ffplay.exe"
            CONVERSOR.StartInfo.Arguments = TextBoxSource.Text 
            CONVERSOR.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False 
            CONVERSOR.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True 
            CONVERSOR.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True 
            CONVERSOR.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True 

            CONVERSOR.Start() 

            While Not CONVERSOR.StandardError.EndOfStream
                TextBoxDETALLES.AppendText(CONVERSOR.StandardError.ReadLine & vbCrLf) 

                Application.DoEvents()
            End While

            MsgBox("HECHO") 
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("Error")
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not trying to convert it, I'm trying to play it.

Comment: That While loop is a bit nasty.. What is the actual problem though? All you've said is what you've done; what would you like us to help with?

Comment: the application doesn't play any ogg file but it doesn't throw any error either.

Comment: Does it work as you expect if you do the same thing on a command prompt?

Comment: not sure how to test it, i'm just getting into programming.

Comment: You click START, type **CMD**, press return, and in the black window that appears type e.g. `ffplay my.ogg`

Comment: that whas I toiught but it throws me this message:
SDL_OpenAudio (2 channels, 22050 Hz): WASAPI can't initialize audio client:  CoInitialize was not called.

SDL_OpenAudio (1 channels, 22050 Hz): WASAPI can't initialize audio client:  CoInitialize was not called.

No more combinations to try, audio open failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223216/discussion-between-rchrd-and-caius-jard).

Comment: Ok, so get it working on the command line first, then transport the working arguments into your code

Comment: Never ever call `Application.DoEvents()`. It is evil incarnate.